# DisplayMemberPath with Indexer in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, indexer

### Starting situation

I want to show a list of `ICameraInfo` in a ComboBox.
ICameraInfo is an interface that give you many infos of a camera. You get each info using [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/).

In my case I want to display the parameter `ICameraInfo[CameraInfoKey.FriendlyName]` in the ComboBox (CameraInfoKey is a static class).

### Code

**In ViewModel:**

```
using Basler.Pylon;
...
public List<ICameraInfo> CamerasFound { get => CameraFinder.Enumerate(); }
```

**In View:**

```
<Window
...
xmlns:bpy="clr-namespace:Basler.Pylon;assembly=Basler.Pylon"/>
...
<ComboBox Name="CamerasList" ItemsSource="{Binding CameraFound }" DisplayMemberPath="[bpy:CameraInfoKey.FriendlyName]" />
```

### Issue

But the binding can't get the value (the ItemsSource isn't the problem, if I remove DisplayMemberPath the list is displayed)
[image: Binding error]

I'm not sure about the `bpy` namespace in XAML to get the static property `CameraInfoKey.FriendlyName` and according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Data_Binding_Path) it is possible to use indexers with Binding, but I'm not sure about the usage either.

**Do you know where the error may have come from?**

Comment: Why are you binding the diplaymember? Just put it inside a quote "FriendlyName" that's it.

Comment: Are you trying to bind to a string property somewhere that has DisplayMemberPath?  If so, those square braces don't like right.  I would expect that should be a proper `{Binding...}` in curly braces and all.

But it might just be simpler to take a look at ICameraInfo for a property that looks like FriendyName and simply use that string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part between the square brackets in the Binding Path can not be a variable. When you write

```
DisplayMemberPath="[bpy:CameraInfoKey.FriendlyName]"
```

the string `"bpy:CameraInfoKey.FriendlyName"` is passed to the indexer property.

A simple solution may be to use the *value* of the `CameraInfoKey.FriendlyName` property in XAML.

Assuming a declaration similar to

```
public class CameraInfoKey
{
    public static string FriendlyName { get; } = "friendly_name";
}
```

the following XAML would work:

```
DisplayMemberPath="[friendly_name]"
```

Answer (score 0):

If `ICameraInfo` does not have `FriendlyName` property that you want and you must get the actual value from an indexer property, I don't think that `DisplayMemberPath` is the way for you to go.  Instead, you should probably layout the `ItemTemplate` for your `ComboBox` and in it, have a TextBlock that pulls the string value.  You could even use a converter for this if necessary.  For example, something like this:

```
// Takes an ICamerInfo value and a string parameter of the key and returns the result of the indexer

public class CameraInfoPropertyConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is not ICameraInfo info)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        if (parameter is not string key)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

        return info[key];
    }
}
```

Then, instead of `DisplayMemberPath`, your `ComboBox` uses the `ItemTemplate` and relies on the converter to go get the property from the indexer

```
<ComboBox Name="CamerasList" ItemsSource="{Binding CameraFound }">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <MyNameSpace:CamerInfoPropertyConveter x:Key="InfoConverter"/>
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyNameSpace:ICameraInfo}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource InfoConverter}, 
                                      ConverterParameter="{x:Static bpy:CameraInfoKey.FriendlyName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Note that I didn't compile this or anything.  And I'm assuming that `bpy:CameraInfoKey.FriendlyName` is truly a statically available string value

Comment: This solution also worked very well. It is more complex than Clemens' but cleaner because I don't have to use the raw `CameraInfoKey.FriendlyName` value directly